# Newbie to C programing: Math Quiz grade printout

Tags: c

Math quiz asks how many problems you want to solve and displays random numbers of addition and subtraction then grades your response to the problems. The thing im having trouble in is printing it out right. I need to display how many I got right and how many I tried all together. example 4 out of 5 correct (**Grade: 2/5 correct)** but im reviving this for example "**Grade: 2/-1832609951**"   Can anyone help thank you!

## include

```
    int main()
    {
     int NumberOfTimes,AddAns,SubAns,AddCorrect=0,SubCorrect=0,CorrectAnsAdd,CorrectAnsSub,TotalCorrect,TotalWrong,Add$
     int i,a,b,c,d,e,f,g;

     printf("\n");
     printf("-------------------MATH QUIZ------------------------\n");
     printf("Enter the number of Math problems you want to solve:");
     scanf("%d", &NumberOfTimes);
     printf("\n");
     srand(time(NULL));
     for (i=0;i<NumberOfTimes;++i)
     {

      b = rand() %3 + 1;
      c = rand() %3 + 1;

      a = rand() %2 + 1;


      if (a == 1)
        {
        printf("%d + %d = ", b,c);
        scanf("%d", &AddAns);
        d = b + c;
        if (AddAns == d)
           {
            printf("  +Correct\n");
            AddCorrect = AddCorrect + 1;
           }
        else
           {
            printf("  +Wrong, it was %d\n", d);
            AddIncorrect = AddIncorrect + 1;
           }
        }
      if (a == 2)
       {
        printf("%d - %d = ", b,c);
        scanf("%d", &SubAns);
        g = b - c;
        if (SubAns == g)
           {
            printf("  +Correct\n");
            SubCorrect = SubCorrect + 1;
           }
        else
           {
            printf("  +Wrong, it was %d\n", g);
            SubIncorrect = SubIncorrect + 1;
           }

       }

      }
      TotalCorrect = AddCorrect + SubCorrect;
      TotalWrong =  AddIncorrect + SubIncorrect;
      printf("\n");
      printf("Grade: %d/%d\n",TotalCorrect,TotalWrong);
      printf("\n");
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: your variable declaration line is incomplete here...what did you write after TotalWrong??

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the problem again and found the solution I should of done this for "number of wrongs/Total"

```
TotalCorrect = AddCorrect + SubCorrect;
  printf("\n");
  printf("Grade: %d/%d\n",TotalCorrect,NumberOfTimes);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
```